# Bootstrap based jquery contact form

Tags: php, jquery, html, contact-form

I'm working on a contact form that uses html,jquery and php to send emails. When i run the code in my web browser i keep getting an error with the jquery section of my code which says
"**Uncaught Syntaxerror:Unexpected token <**".This is the link to the jquery and PHP code:
http://pastebin.com/DV2G4hBA-php code
http://pastebin.com/qnyctaWG-Jquery code.
I need help to solve this problem. thanks

Comment: your error is clearly saying the problem

Comment: The code in the pastebin has been removed.

Answer (score 0):

There is something with the `<` in your code.